# Cut sequence after reaching a key in an array

Tags: php, arrays

Let's imagine I ordered my friends in a list, each of them with certain score, depending on our friendship status. My point is showing the top 3 of them, cutting the sequence with a break. However, my wish is to make id dynamic. What can be placed in "**Rene**" text to make the php dynamic?

```
<?php

$friends = array('Julio' => 9, 'Sergio' => 4, 'Jorge' =>7, 'Rene' => 8, 'Marvin' => 6, 'Brayan' => 5, 'Edvin' => 10, 'Delfido' => 3, 'Jhon' => 2);
arsort($friends);
foreach ($friends as $friend => $score){
  echo $friend . ' ' . $score . '<br>';
  if($friend == '**Rene**'{
    break;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Add a counter. Increment it on every loop iteration. When it hits 3, break.

Comment: You could use [array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to just extract the number of elements you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First you have to order the array on value** (and maintain the key)

```
arsort($friends);
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

**Then count the loop and stop it when it hits 3:**

```
$count = 1;
foreach ($friends as $friend => $score){
    echo $friend . ' ' . $score . '<br>';
    $count++;
    if($count>=3){
        break;
    }
}
```